# IPhone 6 Cell antenna works intermittently

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 6, and the cell antenna does not work at all, except right after it's re-assembled.

I replaced the battery and it worked for about 15 minutes (I activated it and made a call).

Batteries Plus changed the antenna and it did not work, then when they put the old antenna back in and put it back together it worked for a few minutes, similar to my experience.

Is there any hope for this?  I have done at least 6 factory firmware resets with itunes, and am looking for any suggestions for other things to try.

Answer (score 3):

The battery is right up against the antenna and some delicate ribbon connectors that connect to it. It is possible that in the swapping of your battery you might have mis-seated it (at best) or damaged something (at worst).

Did the antenna stop working after you changed the battery and that led you to bring it to a shop? Or was it already getting flaky before you opened it up?

Given that you said that it only worked for about 15 minutes, it is possible that it is either slightly out of place or the ribbon is damaged and the heat of the device is cause expansion/contraction which is causing the antenna to fail; i.e. after a few minutes of using the phone it heats up enough that the connection breaks. No guarantee that cooling it down would reestablish that faulty connection.

Assuming you're comfortable opening the device given that you've already attempted the battery, you could look at loosening and then carefully tightening the antenna screws and see if that helps anything. Step 14 on the [iFixit teardown guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+6+Teardown/29213) gives a closeup of the antenna.

The inside of the phone is delicate and very sensitive to static electricity, things getting bumped, etc. Sure, they're always around static electricity but they're designed to mostly keep that stuff outside of the case. Regardless, given that you mention intermittent behavior you might be able to get away with wiggling / reseating the antenna to bring it back to life. Just make sure to be properly grounded first!

Comment: It does not appear to be a heat issue, it was getting a cell signal for hours this morning until I activated the sim that's in it for my account and then it stopped working again.  My test call (#832) succeeded but after the activation went through it's just saying "searching" now.  Thanks for the link, I'll try that (grounded, of course)

Comment: Also, it was doing the same thing before the battery replacement, I just had it and figured I'd reseat everything while I had it open and see if that helped.

Comment: @mikeb did you ever remove your SIM card by chance? Though I think the message would be different (e.g. "No SIM Card"), it might be worth removing and re-inserting and see if that does anything? Do you have a SIM from another phone you could try?

Comment: I have done this with the SIM (got the no sim card error), and gotten a new one from my provider to try and it still did not work...

Comment: If it is intermittent then I'm suspecting a bad antenna, connection, or something else got messed up. The first two are semi-easy since the antenna is replaceable and the connection can be corrected (usually), but the "else" is a show stopper. You said that the Batteries+ person replaced the antenna but it didn't work? Either they had a dud or your connection is bad. So focusing on the connection, make sure the contacts are clean, there is no finger smudges on it and maybe give it just a SLIGHT extra force when tightening and see if that helps. Otherwise, it might be time to >cough< upgrade